# How to identify row in query results that is causing fatal error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query runs for awhile (outputting rows) and then stops, erroring out with:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 5 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting int to data type numeric.

That doesn't tell me WHICH row (of the rowset formed by the FROM clause - NOT which row in the SQL query) is causing this error.

I used old trick of going to Query Options and unchecking "set arithabort" and "set ansi_warnings", which causes the query to keep running and put a NULL in the offending cell.

The problem is that the result set can correctly have a NULL in a lot of places, so this doesn't help. (and the error message is equally vague: "Arithmetic overflow occurred.")

I'm racking my brain on trying to figure this out - I've thought of using cursors or loops, but there are issues with each.

What do you guys do when you get an error like this, in order to find out which row is causing it?

UPDATE: Thanks for the helpful suggestions below; they are great and work well.  However, before going to that trouble (there are alot of columns in this query), I just wanted to SEE the row that was causing the error.  Luckily, I guessed that the last row in the query result set was the row right before the error occurred.  When I raw a query to see the data right below that row (minus the calculated fields of course), I immediately noticed a larger-than-normal value in one of the INT fields.

This seems like a good first step before going to the trouble of writing queries like the ones below - but thanks, I will save those and surely need them later when the problem isn't this obvious upon looking at the offending data.

Comment: Perhaps you can add the query in the question.

Comment: It's massive - and going through it logically to find error seems like a pain - seems like there should be a way to quickly find the offending row.

Comment: Do you mean the row (like the `Line 5`) in the query or the row in the tables?

Comment: sorry i should have been clear.  I mean the row in the tables (or rather i guess the rowset formed by joining several tables)

Comment: It would really help to see the query, but as a suggestion I would look to see if anywhere in the query it is selecting an `int` value into a `numeric` value and then look at the precision and scale of the `numeric`.  For example, try setting the value 10 to a `numeric(3,2)` variable and you'll get this error.  Also, there may be multiple rows in error.

Comment: Thanks, adrift.  That is how I would typically do it, but I was thinking that if I could quickly find the row in error, I could glance at it and quickly identify potential offending values (or NULLs).  Maybe I'm alone in this desire though, as I've googled and googled and can't find any way to get this information.  Seems really odd that it would give an error and not tell me which row it errored on. (I'm using an order by so ordering is guaranteed)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094483/sql-server-find-out-what-row-caused-the-tsql-to-fail-ssis

Answer (score 1):

We really need to see your SQL.  Are you using a UNION? The first row usually determines the data type.  Are you inserting into another table? (Like I assumed below?)

Change the SELECT part to MAX each of the columns that are of type INT, remove all of the other columns for this test.  The answer will probably be obvious.

```
SELECT MAX(myFirstIntColumn) myFirstIntColumn,
MAX(mySecondIntColumn)
...
FROM same
```

If the answer isn't obvious, look at the columns you are trying to insert into, at least one of the maxes will not fit into one of the targets.  You can confirm this by testing each of the maxes you got with the data type you are trying to insert into.  Something like:

```
 SELECT CAST(1122399 AS DECIMAL(7,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 5 Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

From an int to a numeric, the only error I can think of comes from an overflow of the provisioned number of digits before the decimal place, e.g.

```
select cast(123456 as numeric(7,2))
```

(7,2) means 7 digits in total, having 2 after the decimal place and 5 before.

For such a record, you can find offenders using a query of the type:

```
select ...
  from (... table(s) ...)
 where len(left(replace(cast(col1 as varchar),'.',space(100)),100)) > 5
   and col1 like '%.%'
```

This will flush out columns that are numeric (have decimal) place, and where there are more than 5 digits to the left of the decimal place.