# SQL Server Insert into getting error "String or binary data would be truncated"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an `INSERT INTO` statement where I am inserting around 50000 rows into a table variable. During the insert, I am getting this error

> String or binary data would be truncated

I have checked manually for most of the records there is no data overflow case, please help me find a way where I can get row number which is causing this issue on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: This has been a well known issue for far too long. There are literally thousands of votes on the connect item for this but MS continues to ignore it. It is just awful. You have to dig through the data until you find the cuplrit(s). You can use some sql to help identify the offending rows but it really is a manual process.

Comment: Have you looked [here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094483/sql-server-find-out-what-row-caused-the-tsql-to-fail-ssis) Specifically CarlSteffen's answer.

Comment: Are you obtaining the data by a SELECT statement?  I would try doing a SELECT ...INTO #TEMP FROM.... etc , then use MAX(LEN(...)) on the temp table

Comment: Please provide the table structures (to/from) with data types.

Comment: _"for most of the records there is no data overflow"_ - what does this mean? For some of them there is overflow?

Comment: You could put this in a cursor and insert just one row at a time using PRINT statement to track your progress. It will probably take longer to run, but it will allow you figure out what row is causing the issue.